# Intuit Quickbooks Accounting API OAuth with Developer not working at all

Tags: php, curl, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I only want to grab information using the Quickbooks API (that seems like this should be possible via their API).  I setup an App on their Development site, linked it to the Quickbooks Company I created, and am trying to run this code to get anything from the curl response, but all I am getting are Authorization Failure (401) Messages.  Why is it not being authorized?  Been studying this site for 12 hours and none of their examples that they provide even work.  Am using this page as a reference:  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0010_your_first_request/rest_essentials_for_the_quickbooks_api and this:  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/0015_calling_data_services#/The_authorization_header

My index.php file is as follows:

```
    <?php

define('IS_SANDBOX', 1);

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'oAuth.php');

// GET baseURL/v3/company/companyID/resourceName/entityID
// consumer and consumer_secret
$oAuth = new QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth('qyprdwX21R3klmiskW3AaYLnDRGNLn', 'FDPpxScC6CIgoA07Uc2NYtZJk45CqNDI1Gw4zntn');

$request = array(
    'url' => array(
        'base_request_uri' => IS_SANDBOX == 1 ? 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com' : 'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com',
        'version' => 'v3',
        'company' => 'company',
        'companyID' => '123145768959777'
    ),
    'query' => 'SELECT * FROM ESTIMATE',
    'headers' => array(
        'Host' => IS_SANDBOX == 1 ? 'sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com' : 'quickbooks.api.intuit.com',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'User-Agent' => 'APIExplorer'
    )
);

$request_url = implode('/', $request['url']) . '/query?query=' . str_replace('+', ' ', str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($request['query']))) . '&minorversion=4';

// token, and token_secret
$headers = $oAuth->sign('GET', $request_url, 'qyprdaiy37CxGCuB8ow8XK76FYii3rnRU4AIQrHsZDcVFNnV', 'wWcpmPffdPABp6LNNyYgnraTft7bgdygAmTML0aB');

$request['headers']['Authorization'] = 'OAuth ' . array_pop($headers);

$response = curl($request_url, $request['headers']);

echo '<pre>', var_dump($response), '</pre>';
echo '<pre>', var_dump($request['headers']), '</pre>';


function curl($url, $headers) {
    try {
        $request_headers = array();
        $ch = curl_init();

        if (FALSE === $ch)
            throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        if (!empty($headers)) {

            foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($key == 'GET')
                {
                    $request_headers[] = $key . ' ' . $value;
                    continue;
                }

                $request_headers[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Disable SSL Verfication, so we can get all info from non-SSL site!
        }

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $header = curl_getinfo($ch);

        echo '<h2>Curl Get Info</h2>';
        echo '<pre>', var_dump($header), '</pre>';

        if (FALSE === $data)
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
        else
            return $data;

        curl_close($ch);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
                $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

echo '<pre>', var_dump($request_url), '</pre>';


?>
```

My oAuth.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * QuickBooks PHP DevKit
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Keith Palmer / ConsoliBYTE, LLC.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/eclipse-1.0.php
 * 
 * @author Keith Palmer <keith@consolibyte.com>
 * @license LICENSE.txt 
 * 
 * @package QuickBooks
 */

class QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth
{
    private $_secrets;

    protected $_oauth_consumer_key;
    protected $_oauth_consumer_secret;

    protected $_oauth_access_token;
    protected $_oauth_access_token_secret;

    protected $_version = null;
    protected $_signature = null;
    protected $_keyfile;

    /**
     * 
     */
    const NONCE = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

    const METHOD_POST = 'POST';
    const METHOD_GET = 'GET';
    const METHOD_PUT = 'PUT';
    const METHOD_DELETE = 'DELETE';

    const DEFAULT_VERSION = '1.0';
    const DEFAULT_SIGNATURE = 'HMAC-SHA1';

    const SIGNATURE_PLAINTEXT = 'PLAINTEXT';
    const SIGNATURE_HMAC = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    const SIGNATURE_RSA = 'RSA-SHA1';

    /** 
     * Create our OAuth instance
     */
    public function __construct($oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret)
    {
        $this->_oauth_consumer_key = $oauth_consumer_key;
        $this->_oauth_consumer_secret = $oauth_consumer_secret;

        $this->_version = QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth::DEFAULT_VERSION;
        $this->_signature = QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth::DEFAULT_SIGNATURE;
    }

    /**
     * Set the signature method
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function signature($method, $keyfile = null)
    {
        $this->_signature = $method;
        $this->_keyfile = $keyfile;
    }

    /**
     * Sign an OAuth request and return the signing data (auth string, URL, etc.)
     *
     * 
     */
    public function sign($method, $url, $oauth_token = null, $oauth_token_secret = null, $params = array()) 
    {
        /*
        print('got in: [' . $method . '], ' . $url);
        print_r($params);
        print('<br /><br /><br />');
        */

        if (!is_array($params))
        {
            $params = array();
        }

        $params = array_merge($params, array(
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->_oauth_consumer_key, 
            'oauth_signature_method' => $this->_signature, 
            'oauth_nonce' => $this->_nonce(), 
            'oauth_timestamp' => $this->_timestamp(), 
            'oauth_version' => $this->_version,
            ));

        // Add in the tokens if they were passed in
        if ($oauth_token)
        {
            $params['oauth_token'] = $oauth_token;
        }

        if ($oauth_token_secret)
        {
            $params['oauth_secret'] = $oauth_token_secret;
        }

        // Generate the signature
        $signature_and_basestring = $this->_generateSignature($this->_signature, $method, $url, $params);

        $params['oauth_signature'] = $signature_and_basestring[1];

        /*
        print('<pre>');
        print('BASE STRING IS [' . $signature_and_basestring[0] . ']' . "\n\n");
        print('SIGNATURE IS: [' . $params['oauth_signature'] . ']');
        print('</pre>');
        */

        $normalized = $this->_normalize($params);

        /*
        print('NORMALIZE 1 [' . $normalized . ']' . "\n");
        print('NORMZLIZE 2 [' . $this->_normalize2($params) . ']' . "\n");
        */

        if (false !== ($pos = strpos($url, '?')))
        {
            $url = substr($url, 0, $pos);
        }

        $normalized_url = $url . '?' . $normalized;         // normalized URL

        return array (
            0 => $signature_and_basestring[0],      // signature basestring
            1 => $signature_and_basestring[1],      // signature
            2 => $normalized_url, 
            3 => $this->_generateHeader($params, $normalized),  // header string
            );
    }

    protected function _generateHeader($params, $normalized) 
    {
        // oauth_signature="' . $this->_escape($params['oauth_signature']) . '", 
        $str = '';

        if (isset($params['oauth_token']))
            $str .= rawurlencode('oauth_token') . '="' . rawurlencode($params['oauth_token']) . '", ';

        $nonce = rawurlencode(md5(mt_rand()));

        $nonce_chars = str_split($nonce);

        $formatted_nonce = '';
        foreach($nonce_chars as $n => $chr)
        {
            if (in_array($n, array(8, 12, 16, 20)))
                $formatted_nonce .= '-';

            $formatted_nonce .= $chr;
        }

        $str .= rawurlencode('oauth_nonce') . '="' . $formatted_nonce . '", ' . 
            rawurlencode('oauth_consumer_key') . '="' . rawurlencode($params['oauth_consumer_key']) . '", ' . 
            rawurlencode(oauth_signature_method) . '="' . rawurlencode($params['oauth_signature_method']) . '", ' .
            rawurlencode(oauth_timestamp) . '="' . rawurlencode($params['oauth_timestamp']) . '", ' . 
            rawurlencode(oauth_version) . '="' . rawurlencode($params['oauth_version']) . '", ' . 
            rawurlencode(oauth_signature) . '="' . $this->_escape($params['oauth_signature']) . '"';

        return str_replace(array(' ', '  ', '   '), '', str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), ' ', $str));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    protected function _escape($str) 
    {
        if ($str === false)
        {
            return $str;
        }
        else
        {
            return str_replace('+', ' ', str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($str)));
        }
    }

    protected function _timestamp()
    {
        //return 1326976195;

        //return 1318622958;
        return time();
    }

    protected function _nonce($len = 5) 
    {
        //return '1234';

        $tmp = str_split(QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth::NONCE);
        shuffle($tmp);

        //return 'kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg';
        return substr(implode('', $tmp), 0, $len);
    }

    protected function _normalize($params)
    {   
        $normalized = array();

        ksort($params);
        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            // all names and values are already urlencoded, exclude the oauth signature
            if ($key != 'oauth_secret')
            {
                if (is_array($value))
                {
                    $sort = $value;
                    sort($sort);
                    foreach ($sort as $subkey => $subvalue)
                    {
                        $normalized[] = $this->_escape($key) . '=' . $this->_escape($subvalue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $normalized[] = $this->_escape($key) . '=' . $this->_escape($value);
                }
            }
        }

        return implode('&', $normalized);
    }

    protected function _generateSignature($signature, $method, $url, $params = array()) 
    {
        /*
        print('<pre>params for signing');
        print_r($params);
        print('</pre>');
        */

        //if (false !== strpos($url, 'get_access'))
        /*if (true)
        {
            print($url . '<br />' . "\r\n\r\n");
            die('NORMALIZE MINE [' . $this->_normalize($params) . ']');
        }*/

        /*
        print('<pre>');
        print('NORMALIZING [' . "\n");
        print($this->_normalize($params) . "]\n\n\n");
        print('SECRET KEY FOR SIGNING [' . $secret . ']' . "\n");
        print('</pre>');
        */

        if (false !== ($pos = strpos($url, '?')))
        {
            $tmp = array();
            parse_str(substr($url, $pos + 1), $tmp);

            // Bad hack for magic quotes... *sigh* stupid PHP
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                foreach ($tmp as $key => $value)
                {
                    if (!is_array($value))
                    {
                        $tmp[$key] = stripslashes($value);
                    }
                }
            }

            $params = array_merge($tmp, $params);

            $url = substr($url, 0, $pos);
        }

        //print('url [' . $url . ']' . "\n");
        //print_r($params);

        $sbs = $this->_escape($method) . '&' . $this->_escape($url) . '&' . $this->_escape($this->_normalize($params));

        //print('sbs [' . $sbs . ']' . "\n");

        // Which signature method? 
        switch ($signature)
        {
            case QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth::SIGNATURE_HMAC:
                return $this->_generateSignature_HMAC($sbs, $method, $url, $params);    
            case QuickBooks_IPP_OAuth::SIGNATURE_RSA:
                return $this->_generateSignature_RSA($sbs, $method, $url, $params);
        }

        return false;
    }


    /*
        // Pull the private key ID from the certificate
        $privatekeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($cert);

        // Sign using the key
        $sig = false;
        $ok  = openssl_sign($base_string, $sig, $privatekeyid);   

        // Release the key resource
        openssl_free_key($privatekeyid);

        base64_encode($sig)
    */


    protected function _generateSignature_RSA($sbs, $method, $url, $params = array())
    {
        // $res = ... 
        $res = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://' . $this->_keyfile);

        /*
        print('key id is: [');
        print_r($res);
        print(']');
        print("\n\n\n");
        */

        $signature = null;
        $retr = openssl_sign($sbs, $signature, $res);

        openssl_free_key($res);

        return array(
            0 => $sbs, 
            1 => base64_encode($signature), 
            );
    }



    /*
    $key = $request->urlencode($consumer_secret).'&'.$request->urlencode($token_secret);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $key, true));
    */  

    protected function _generateSignature_HMAC($sbs, $method, $url, $params = array())
    {
        $secret = $this->_escape($this->_oauth_consumer_secret);

        $secret .= '&';

        if (!empty($params['oauth_secret']))
        {
            $secret .= $this->_escape($params['oauth_secret']);
        }

        //print('generating signature from [' . $secret . ']' . "\n\n");

        return array(
            0 => $sbs, 
            1 => base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $sbs, $secret, true)), 
            );
    }
}
?>
```

`$request['headers']` looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["Host"]=>
  string(33) "sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(11) "APIExplorer"
  ["Authorization"]=>
  string(306) "OAuth oauth_token="qyprdaiy37CxGCuB8ow8XK76FYii3rnRU4AIQrHsZDcVFNnV",oauth_nonce="189f7f21-6dd9-c136-e208-0f33141feea5",oauth_consumer_key="qyprdwX21R3klmiskW3AaYLnDRGNLn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1462545676",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="BIpYveqCxlfVT4Ps4qJypS%2BXHh8%3D""
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401
            SignatureBaseString: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F123145768959777%2Fquery&minorversion%3D4%26oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdwX21R3klmiskW3AaYLnDRGNLn%26oauth_nonce%3D189f7f21-6dd9-c136-e208-0f33141feea5%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1462545676%26oauth_token%3Dqyprdaiy37CxGCuB8ow8XK76FYii3rnRU4AIQrHsZDcVFNnV%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26query%3DSELECT%2520%252A%2520FROM%2520ESTIMATE
```

The `$request_url` looks like this:

`https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145768959777/query?query=SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20ESTIMATE&minorversion=4`

Am I forgetting to do something here?  Or perhaps something is not correct somehow?  I should be getting All Estimates from within the Quickbook Company with ID of `123145768959777`, but all I'm getting is 401 Authorization Failure messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I forgetting to do something here? Or perhaps something is not correct somehow?

Yes, definitely. See below for specifics:

> $headers = $oAuth->sign(null, ...

`null` is not a valid HTTP request method. Valid HTTP request methods are things like `GET`, `POST`, etc. Please refer to the HTTP spec and the OAuth spec.

> $headers = $oAuth->sign(null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],

Why are you signing the server request URI? You should be signing the URL that *you are sending your curl request to* and not the URL the user is visiting on your own website.

> $headers = $oAuth->sign(null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'qyprdaiy37CxGCuB8ow8XK76FYii3rnRU4AIQrHsZDcVFNnV', 'wWcpmPffdPABp6LNNyYgnraTft7bgdygAmTML0aB');

You can not hard-code the OAuth access token and secret. They change every 6 months, and thus have to be stored in a database/file somewhere so that you can change them without editing your code every 6 months.

> $request_url = implode('/', $request['url']) . '/query?query=' . str_replace('+', ' ', str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($request['query']))) . '&minorversion=4';

This is the URL you should be signing.

> I should be getting All Estimates from within the Quickbook Company with ID of 123145768959777, but all I'm getting is 401 Authorization Failure messages.

If you need further help, it would make a lot of sense to post your actual HTTP requests and responses. There's not a lot anyone will be able to tell you without really seeing the requests being sent, and the responses being received.

Also... you realize that all of this hard work has already been done for you, using the library you've grabbed code from, right? e.g. You don't need to do any of what you're doing - it's just re-inventing the wheel. Just do:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

$EstimateService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Estimate();
$estimates = $EstimateService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Estimate STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 10");

foreach ($estimates as $Estimate)
{
    print('Estimate # ' . $Estimate->getDocNumber() . "\n");
}
```

Helpful links:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_query.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, here is my response from the curl request:  `message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401
            SignatureBaseString: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F123145768959777%2Fquery&minorversion%3D4%26oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdwX21R3klmiskW3AaYLnDRGNLn%26oauth_nonce%3Ddbc677e1-3992-0ae4-0063-9b861998c265%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1462545469%26oauth_token%3Dqyprdaiy37CxGCuB8ow8XK76FYii3rnRU4AIQrHsZDcVFNnV%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26query%3DSELECT%2520%252A%2520FROM%2520ESTIMATE`

Comment: Made changes as per your recommendations, but still no dice.

Comment: But you didn't post your updated code, or the HTTP request/response from your updated code, so I can't really help you any further...

Comment: Ok, give me sec, updating it now.

Comment: The links you provided have corrupt information, that no longer is relevant for that git repo... For example, it says to go to `docs/example_app_ipp_v3/`, but that directory structure doesn't even exist in your git repo.  Ok, nevermind, it was moved I suppose...  found it after some digging...

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to connect to the quickbooks API using your git repo.  I got the files structured so that it within the root of the site.  Is there any files that should be removed from your repo when online?  Also, you stated every 6 months this needs to be renewed in the database?  Does this get done automatically, or does it require an action?  I will need to hit the url(s) after an action from another url is completed.

Comment: Also, I do not understand the relevance of `$the_tenant`, can you explain that?

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't leave all of the examples accessible obviously. They are, after all, example scripts that print out or add data to QuickBooks. There is a reconnect script which shows you how to reconnect. You could cron schedule it or move it inline with the configuration. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/reconnect.php

Comment: Are you building a multi-tenant SaaS application (e.g. do you have multiple QuickBooks Online companies connecting to your app)?  If so, then set $the_tenant to YOUR unique identifier for each of your tenants. Otherwise, leave it set as a constant.

Comment: No, just 1 Company.  Thanks!